# Why Serial number is vanished in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I am generating Auto Serial number in DataGridView using below code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        table.Columns.Add("Sl", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        table.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Amount", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))


        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DgvRowCountChanged()
        For Each dgvr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            dgvr.Cells(0).Value = dgvr.Index + 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
        Me.DgvRowCountChanged()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsRemoved(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsRemoved
        Me.DgvRowCountChanged()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim Index As Integer
        
    If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
        Index = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Index)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Serial number appears, but when I click on next column it disappears. Why is that happening?

Comment: Firstly, don't do this: `Type.GetType("System.Int32")`. Do this::`GetType(Integer)`. That way, you get compile-time type-checking. Only use a `String` to specify a type if you have to have it coming from an external source. If you're hard-coding the type, use a data type, not a `String` containing the name of a type.

Comment: As for the issue, the `DataGridView` class does some stuff in the background that should not be an issue if you use it right, but you're not using it right. You should not be doing anything with the grid directly. That's for the user. You should bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`, bind that to the grid and then work with the `BindingSource` in code. A `BindingSource` is supposed to be the one place you work with bound data so if you want to work with bound data, that's what you should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this, make life easy:

- Ditch all that code
- Make a new form
- Add a new item of type DataSet to your project, and give it a nice name (not DataSet1)
- Double click the dataset, so its design surface appears
- Right click the surface, choose "Add new.. DataTable", give it a more imaginative name than DataTable1. I'll assume you choose License (serial number? name? seems licensey)
- Right click the new datatable and choose "Add New.. Column"
- Name the new column Sl, and use the properties grid to give it a type of System.Int32
- Repeat for your other columns
- Save
- Open the Data Sources window on the View menu (Other Windows item)
- Open the new blank form you made in step 2
- Expand every node you can see in the Data Sources window
- Drag the node representing your datatable (the one with an icon looking like a datagridview next toit) out of the data sources window and drop it on the form
- Remove (delete) the bindingnavigator it created (you wont need it)
- CLick the datagridview, CLick the small arrow that appeared in the top right of the control to show the popup menu, choose Edit Columns
- Make whatever columns you want read only
- Set other properties like sizes of columns, fill weights, header texts etc
- Open the code of your form. add a single row of data to the datatable, in the constructor, after the initializecomponent() call:

  Me.myImaginativeDataSetName.License.AddLicenseRow(1, 1, "Name Blah", 1234)

That's it. It looks like a lot because I've broken it down into the absolute step by step - about the only thing that isn't there is reminding you to take a breath every few steps because you'll be so blown away how easy it makes your life when you get the IDE to write code for you, ;)

OK, it's maybe not that exciting... But you already use the Forms designer to write reams of code for you, so this is how you leverage the other tools so you don't have to work with un-typed datasets all the time. Ugh.

The dataset this creates has a full suite of nicely named properties; don't use the basic stringy stuff ever again:

```
'yes - do this
For Each ro as LicenseRow in myDataSet.License
  If ro.IsNameNull Then ro.Name = "Default Name" & ro.Sl
Next ro

'no - heck no
For Each ro as DataRow in myDataSet.Tables("License").Rows
  If ro.IsNull("Naem") Then ro.item("Name") = "Default Name" & Convert.ToInt32(ro.Item("Sl"))
Next ro
```

See how much cleaner the first one is? ro.Sl is a nice Integer property, no casting or converting, no incessant Tables this or Columns/Rows that, Intellisense helps you out becaise it's all strongly named stuff, no typos in string column names like I made in the second...

---

It looks like youre trying to prevent the user from adding rows with this:

```
If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
    Index = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Index)
    End If
End Sub
```

If so, click the datagridview on the form designer and in the properties grid set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false. If youre also trying to prevent deletion set the same on `AllowUserToDeleteRows`

Comment: excellent! the last code is for Deleting row by clicking button. All is okay now, except, Serial is breaking while trying to delete row from middle.

Comment: Oh, serial is an incrementing number? Should be easy enough using, the [datatable rowdeleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted?view=netcore-3.1) event to enumerate the table something like `For Each ro In myDs.License.Where(Function(x) x.Sl > deletedRow.Sl)` `ro.Sl -= 1` - run a where query for all rows with a higher Serial number and decrement them by 1